# Make CountVectorizer faster for Large dataset

Tags: python-3.x, performance, scikit-learn, countvectorizer

Hello i want to cluster movies based on their title only. My function works really good for my data but i have a big problem my sample is big 150.000 movies and its very slow actually took 3 days to cluster all movies

Process:

Sort movie titles based on their length

Transform movies with countvectorizer and calculate the similarity for each one (for every clustered movie i fit the vectorizer every time and i transform the target movie)

```
def product_similarity( clustered_movie, target_movie ):

'''
Calculates the title distance of 2 movies based on title
'''
# fitted vectorizer is a dictionary with fitted movies if wee dont fit to 
# vectorizer the movie it fits and save it to dictionary

if clustered_movie in fitted_vectorizer: 
    vectorizer = fitted_vectorizer[clustered_movie]

    a = vectorizer.transform([clustered_movie]).toarray()
    b = vectorizer.transform( [target_movie] ).toarray()
    similarity = cosine_similarity( a, b )

else:
    clustered_movie = re.sub("[0-9]|[^\w']|[_]", " ",clustered_product )

    vectorizer = CountVectorizer(stop_words=None)
    vectorizer = vectorizer.fit([clustered_movie])

    fitted_vectorizer[clustered_movie] = vectorizer

    a = vectorizer.transform([clustered_movie]).toarray()
    b = vectorizer.transform( [target_movie] ).toarray()
    similarity = cosine_similarity( a, b )

return similarity[0][0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Fit the CountVectorizer one time, on all titles. Save the model. Then transform using the fitted model.

Comment: Why would the 2-step be faster than a simple 'fit-transform'?

Comment: @LeiHao Because you fit once, instead of fitting $n$ times, where $n$ is the number of movie clusters. Fitting takes more time than transforming, because fitting requires a distributed sort, while transform is does not require any distributed operations in Spark; it is one on one executor.

Comment: It is still HUGE. Like 1.2 GB in size. And I have 100k tokens; do you have any suggestions?